# Android - sending instance of class X from activity A to activity B

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, runtimeexception

From my Mainactivity I'm trying to send my Connection class to my Mapsactivity so I can use methods in my Connection class from my Mapsactivity.

For some reason I'm getting this error when starting my Mapsactivity,

java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

I'm not really sure what the problem is, my Connection class has implemented Serializable, I've also let my Mainactivity implement Serializable to see if it would fix but with no success.

My app is supposed to let people connect to a server where they send their location to and receive locations from others connected and have the coordinates put on their map. I've removed code that has nothing related to this problem so there's less to read. I belive I've gotten all the necessary code, if it's not enough I can post whole classes.
Thanks in advance

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
private Connection connection;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialize();
    setListeners();
}

public void initialize() {
    connection = new Connection("xxx.xxx.xxx.x",xxxx);
    btnShowMap = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowMap);
    Log.w(null, "Initialized");
}

public void startMap() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("class", connection);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void setListeners() {
    btnShowMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnShowMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startMap();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Connection class

```
    public class Connection implements Serializable{
private InetAddress address;
private int port;
private String ip, groupName, myName, total, membersInfo, id, fName;
private Socket socket;
private InputStream is;
private DataInputStream dis;
private OutputStream os;
private DataOutputStream dos;
private boolean connected = false;
private double latitude, longitude, fLong ,fLat;
private String name;
private double Longi, Lati;

public Connection(String ip, int port){
    this.ip = ip;
    this.port = port;
}

public void listenToServer() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ListenToServer());
    thread.start();
}

private class ListenToServer implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Log.w(null,"Listening to server");
        try {
            String locations = new String(dis.readUTF());
            if(locations == null) {
                Log.e(null,"EMPTY");
            }
            if(locations != null) {
                JSONObject friends = new JSONObject(locations);
                JSONArray jsonArray = friends.getJSONArray("location");
                JSONObject transaction;
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    transaction = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    fName = transaction.getString("member");
                    fLong = transaction.getDouble("longitude");
                    fLat = transaction.getDouble("latitude");
                }
            }
            if (locations == null) {
                dis.close();
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

MapsActivity class

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
private double latitude, longitude, flat, flong;
private String friendName;
private boolean addMarker = false;
private Connection connection;
private Button btnAddMyMarker, btnAddFriendMarker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    initialize();
    setListener();
}

public void initialize() {
    btnAddMyMarker = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddMyMarker);
    btnAddMyMarker.setEnabled(false);
    btnAddFriendMarker = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddFriendMarker);
    connection = (Connection) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("class");
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocList();

}

public void setListener() {
    btnAddMyMarker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addMyMarker();
        }
    });

    btnAddFriendMarker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            connection.listenToServer();
        }
    });
}


public void addMyMarker() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("My position"));
}

private class LocList implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        if(addMarker == false && longitude != 0 && latitude != 0) {
            btnAddMyMarker.setEnabled(true);
        }
        connection.sendLocation(latitude, longitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to pass `Connection` between activities, as most of what's in it cannot be serialized or converted into a `Parcel`. Of note, none of the following will support either operation:

```
private InputStream is;
private DataInputStream dis;
private OutputStream os;
private DataOutputStream dos;
```

Either:

- This should be a service, particularly if work should be done independent of any UI, or
- This will need to be a singleton, or
- Don't have separate activities, but rather one activity with multiple fragments, or
- Isolate all the connection-related work into a single activity

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare said you need to reconsider your design, a connection is usually independent of the activities you have, since most of the activities might have to use it as you noticed yourself.

What you can do is make a subclass of `Application` as a way to maintain `Connection` as a global instance accessible by all your activities: like a singleton for example.

```
    public class MyApp extends Application{

          public void onCreate(){
            super.onCreate();           
          }

          private static Connection con=null;

          private Connection(){

             //initialize a connection here

          }

          public static Connection getConnection(){

              if(con==null){

             con=new Connection();
             return con;
              }else{

               return con;
              }        

          }
     }
```

This way you could access the Connection `con` from any Activity just by calling MyApp.getConnection().Just don't forget to add `MyApp` to you manifest

[This link should be helpful](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)